Craft CMS + Formie Form Repeater Field
I have checkbox list and each item has repeater field with many other fields inside it. Some fields inside repeater are conditional. I tried to give condition from admin form but in condition, repeater field not showing. so i have show/hide field using JavaScript.
As field which is going to show/hide are required, even its hidden, form couldn't be submit because of required field. How can I achieve this?
Show hide like this using JS
 $("div[data-field-handle='fenceType'] select[data-fui-id='LandscapingFrontyardDesignChanges2-fencingWallsNonRetaining1-fenceType']").each(function(){
      $(this).change(function(){                
             if ($(this).val().includes("Other")) {
             $(this).closest(".fui-row").next().find("div[data-field-handle='describeOtherFenceDesignType']").show();
                    }
               else{
                 $(this).closest(".fui-row").next().find("div[data-field-handle='describeOtherFenceDesignType']").hide();
               }
      });   
  }); 

